# Find the number of such $4$-tuples $(a,b,c,d)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

If $a \in\{1,2\}$, $b \in\{1,2,4\}$, $c\in\{1,2,3,6\}$ and $d\in\{1,2,4\}$.Find the number of $4$-tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ such that lcm$(a,b,c,d)=12$.

Comment: Case 1: $c=6$.  Case 2: $c=3$.  There are no other cases.

Comment: Hint: if lcm = 12 one must be a multiple of 3. So c=3 or 6. If none of a b d is a multiple of 4, the the lcm is 6; not 12. So a b and d must be 1 1 and 4 in some order and c=3. So a = 1. So there are two possibilities b,d = 1,4 or b,d = 4,1.

Comment: Notice that $a$ and $b$ are not limited to $1$ and $4;$ they can be $2$ as well, with the stipulation that *at least one* of the two is $4.$ LCM disregards smaller powers of each prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that since $12 = 3 \times 2^{2},$ either $b$ or $d$ has to be equal to $4$ and $c$ *has* to be either $3$ or $6$ in order to satisfy the least common multiple of $12.$ Using constructive counting, we find that because there are $5$ ways to choose values for $b$ and $d$ (*at least one* is a $4$), $2$ ways to choose $c$ (either $3$ or $6$), and $2$ ways to choose $a,$ which has really no limitations, our answer is $5 \times 2 \times 2 = \boxed{20}.$